# How to change the language of an output of a linear model in R?

Tags: r

Sys.setenv(LANG = "it") solves the language issue in another domain. Does the language depend on the hard-coded base R functions?

Comment: Not sure what the problem is: https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/trunk/src/library/stats/R/lm.R shows it uses `gettextf` for formatting text, and they have [`it.po`](https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/trunk/src/library/stats/po/it.po). Perhaps you could post code that demonstrates otherwise?

Comment: @r2evans, those hooks are only for messages/warnings/errors. I'm assuming the OP wants translations of the words in the `print` and `summary` methods (e.g. "Coefficients", "Residual standard error", etc.).  These appear to be hard-coded.

Comment: Good call, @BenBolker, then I guess https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/trunk/src/library/stats/R/lm.R#L244-L245 shows that "no", it is not being translated?